# Django: IE doesn't load localhost or loads very SLOWLY

Tags: django, performance, internet-explorer, loading

I'm just starting to learn Django, building a project on my computer, running Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7, Django 1.3.

Basically whatever I write, it loads in Chrome and Firefox instantly. But for IE (version 9), it just stalls there, and does nothing. I can load up "http://127.0.0.1:8000" on IE and leave the computer on for hours and it doesn't load. Sometimes, when I refresh a couple of times or restart IE it'll work. If I change something in the code, again, Chrome and Firefox reflects changes instantly, whereas IE doesn't - if it loads the page at all.

What is going on? I'm losing my mind here....

Comment: I'm not sure what causes IE to behave that way, but I've seen the exact same behavior. I do my development on Linux and when doing cross-platform testing, run the dev server on a specific IP:8000. I've noticed that IE will make a few requests, then stop. I'll restart the dev server and it will work again for a few requests.

Comment: on my mac (Mountain Lion) I can use the development server only with Chrome, on Firefox and Safari it stuck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be related to this issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16099

Essentially, the dev server isn't multithreaded, and if the browser opens a connection and then tries a second connection to actually get the data, it can hang forever.

Edit:

Also, see this issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15178

If you can provide a way to reproduce the issue, we may be able to find a fix.

Also, if you could try the latest development version and see if that fixes it, we recently committed a new patch that adds multithreading capability to the runserver command.

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem. Once I shut down other browsers and only used IE to open up the page on the dev server, it worked every time. But it's still a bit slower than Chrome or Firefox... but I guess I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: Indeed, I filled ticket 15178 and just confirmed that using the multithreaded development server fixes it. The fix is in revision 16427.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the same problem as me. But I also bumped with the same white page on IE9 and apparently it was caused by html tag "fieldset" hides my form.

Try to validate your html code or check html tags compatibility with IE9. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing with Windows 7, 64bit, django 1.3, py 2.6 and I always check functionality of the Dev server in IE, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. My newest system has IE9 on it and my old system has IE8. I also noticed the hanging problem. I found that when I used 127.0.0.1:8000 it hung and would take refreshed to get it to work. If I started the Dev server using the specific IP address of my dev server the problem seemed to be gone. For example python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.134:8000

Does seem to be something very specific to IE9. an if you google it more people have been seeing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue too, this workaround does the fix. works only for django <= 1.3
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201103/quick_and_dirty_multithreaded_django_dev_server.html

@Andrew Barber
**EDIT**
summary/how i did that:
create a file named managec.py (c=concurrent)
paste the following code in there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# 
# A clone of manage.py, with multi-threadedness monkeypatched in.

import os, sys
from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    sys.stderr.write(
        "Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. "
        "It appears you've customized things.\n"
        "You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n"
        "(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" 
        % __file__
        )
    sys.exit(1)

def monkey_patch_for_multi_threaded():
    # This monkey-patches BaseHTTPServer to create a base HTTPServer class that 
    # supports multithreading 
    import BaseHTTPServer, SocketServer 
    OriginalHTTPServer = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer

    class ThreadedHTTPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, OriginalHTTPServer): 
        def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass=None): 
            OriginalHTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass) 

    BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer = ThreadedHTTPServer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    monkey_patch_for_multi_threaded()
    execute_manager(settings)
```

start your dev server with ./**managec.py** runserver 8080 (or whatever port you use) 
enjoy :)

Comment: Could you summarize the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when you have unusual code like I have a line taking input from the users before HttpResponse. Remove that code and refresh the server. It will work like charm.