# IE 9 still doesn’t work with Django dev server as of Dec 2011

Tags: django, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: IE doesn't load locahost or loads very SLOWLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046625/django-ie-doesnt-load-locahost-or-loads-very-slowly)

I just set up a clean dev environment on a computer running Windows 7 64-bit and installed all the latest officially released 64-bit versions of my tools including Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7.2.  I also got all the OS updates from MS and the computer vendor (HP), which I assume include fixes for IE9 bugs.

I am seeing exactly the same problem as reported 6 months ago in this StackOverflow question originally posed back on May 18 2011:

[Django: IE doesn't load localhost or loads very SLOWLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046625/django-ie-doesnt-load-locahost-or-loads-very-slowly)

That is, Firefox works fine but IE9 hangs.  The Django dev server , which seems to be running single threaded, seems to complete passing the response to the client and then sits waiting for the next request.  IE9 however seems to think that it has not gotten the complete response (even though it has, including static pages referenced in the main page, to judge from the fact that it gets into the cache and can be gotten via am “X” disconnect  followed by a refresh.)

My question is, is there a definitive resolution for this problem?  In a response to the original question dated Aug 23 2011 Catalin Iacob says “I filled ticket 15178 and just confirmed that using the multithreaded development server fixes it. The fix is in revision 16427.”  I am running the final Django 1.3.1 but I don’t know what its revision number is.  Is the fix in question in 1.3.1?  Do I have to enable multithreading with an option in settings.py or whatever?

EDIT: Thanks to user1043838 and nagisa and maybe others to come for posting concrete constructive solutions to the problem.  I will try the fix that goes into settings.py because it’s non-invasive and easy to back out, but in general I want to work in as vanilla an environment as possible (Windows env that is).  The problem bothers me but is far from a show-stopper at this point – firefox + firebug etc. is better for testing anyway – and if the cause is not outdated or misconfigured software then I can deal.

Comment: I spent 1 year working with Django in a Windows environment and it was hell. The Django core developers does not care about Windows. Many tests cases of the Django test suit fails under Windows.

Comment: I would say that "not care" sounds to harsh, it's not that they don't care it's just that there isn't lot of core devs using windows and Django is community driven project. Also this is not IE only problem, same thing happend in Chrome a while ago. Multi-threaded dev server should solve the issue.

Comment: IE is the worst currently used browser.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't use Windows.

I will post multi threaded server fix as answer as I have a hunch that this is purely connection concurrency related problem.

In your project manage.py file add

```
import settings
# Multithreaded server...
if settings.DEBUG:
    import SocketServer
    import django.core.servers.basehttp
    django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIServer = \
        type('WSGIServer',
             (SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,
              django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIServer,
              object),
             {})
```

just before `if __name__ == "__main__":` line. Then rerun your server by using same `manage.py runserver` and it should run as multi threaded server.

But be aware, it is even less stable than single threaded server and it tends to not serve files at all sometimes.

Comment: This works quite fine, except that I keep getting `[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` when I do a full page reload.

However, I only need IE9 for debugging IE9 javascript issues, so this solution helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fairly well on Internet Explorer 10 Developer Preview on Windows 8 x64 Developer Preview with Django version 1.4 pre-alpha SVN-17202 running Satchmo version 0.9.2-pre hg-unknown.

Maybe upgrade?